# How can I GROUP_CONCAT values in mySQL with a SEPERATOR "<br>" but without breaking lines?

Tags: html, mysql

When I use in mySQL request...

```
GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR " <br> ") AS texts
```

...my result in my html table is:

```
My name is 
Fred
My age is 24
My friend's 
name is Toni
My job is 
teacher
```

But I would need a kind of nowrap result for each element:

```
My name is Fred
My age is 24
My friend's name is Toni
My job is teacher
```

I need a solution directly inside the mySQL request:

Comment: Can you show us a data sample of `text` column?

Comment: We'll be able to help you more easily if you show us the raw HTML emitted by your application to your browser. It looks to me like you are rendering the output of your `GROUP_CONCAT()` operation in a table cell that's too narrow for the text, so your browser is line-wrapping it. But that's nothing but a guess.

Comment: @O.Jones Yes, its true, the browser is line wrapping. That is why I was looking for a solution to use white-space:no-wrap but inside the mySQL request

Comment: @Jarla Then enclose `GROUP_CONCAT` in a DIV with `white-space:no-wrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily when using a `<div>` or `<td>` element that's too small for its contents, one uses css to enlarge the element or maybe the table column. That seems to be difficult in this case.

If your text is too wide for your column you should change `" <br> "` to `"<br>"` to eliminate the extra spacing.

You could try swapping out all the space characters for non-breaking spaces, like so.

```
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR '<br>'), ' ', '&nbsp;' AS texts
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
 GROUP_CONCAT(replace(text,"\r\n","") SEPARATOR " <br> ") AS texts
```

Comment: Is it the same result? Is there a new line in the text in table?

Comment: The same result

Comment: Please try if any of these work:

GROUP_CONCAT(replace(text,"\r","") SEPARATOR " <br> ") AS texts                                       
GROUP_CONCAT(replace(text,"\n","") SEPARATOR " <br> ") AS texts